# timestamp on mysql query

Tags: php

i have a search engine, which grabs links and titles from a mysql database and loops them into a page which matches what the user inputs. it is a query essentially and i would like to know how i could create a stamp which calculates a) how many rows are being returned and b) how long it took the query to return the results. any ideas?

for example, if i input 'google' the search engine returns the results for 'Google', above the results however, in small writing, i would like it to show how long the query took, to about 4 decimal places and how many rows are being displayed.

```
 $query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE "; 

$terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
$i = 0; 
foreach ($terms as $each) {
      if ($i++ !== 0){
            $query .= " AND "; 
      }
      $query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%'";
}
// Don't append the ORDER BY until after the loop
$query .= "ORDER BY rank";



$query = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {
        if ($k == "Paralympics 2012" ) {
                    echo "<h1> Paralympic Event: Archery  </h1>";
                }
                 if ($k == "paralympics 2012") {
                 echo "<h1> Paralympic Event: Archery </h1>";

            }
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['keywords'];
            $link = $row['link'];
            $rank = $row['rank'];
```

Comment: [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: Please don't be harsh on new users. Noah, what have you tried?

Comment: i dont know where to start, any idea? the code is now above

Comment: @MadaraUchiha After 47 questions it isn't new anymore :)

Comment: @PeeHaa: He was new when I wrote that comment. He's also suspended since then.

Answer (score 1):

You take the `microtime()` before you executed the query, and the `microtime()` after you executed the query, substract the two, and you have the time it took to execute it in microseconds.